# Use divs instead of bullets for Orbit

Tags: jquery, zurb-foundation, orbit

Orbit comes built in with a bullet nav system. Instead of using those bullets to navigate between slides, I'd like to use items in a nav menu on my page to do the same thing. Is there an elegant way of basically substituting a series of divs for the bullets so that when I click on one of my divs it will cause Orbit to scroll to the appropriate slide? Would it be wiser just to create my own content slider? Thanks in advance for any advice you might have.

Comment: Foundation 4 is supposed to be released within a week, so who knows if any Orbit updates will include easier customization....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was looking for a way to do this also - it seems like this should probably be built in down the track for greater flexibility.

I had a quick look and tweaked this solution https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/118/ using orbit 1.4.0.

You use whatever structure you like for the nav:

```
<div id="custom-orbit-nav">
   <div>1</div>
   <div>2</div>
   <div>3</div>
</div>
```

Then bind the navigation divs with jquery, and use the orbit functions to change slide index, here's my initialization code:

```
$("#featured").orbit();
$("#custom-orbit-nav div").click(function() {
    var myIndex = $(this).index();
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $("#featured").trigger("orbit.stop").trigger("orbit.goto", [myIndex]);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Good solution. This enables you to have multiple Orbits on a page, whereas mine does not. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have bullets enabled when you set up Orbit. That will look something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#yourOrbitElement").orbit({
    bullets: true
  });
});
```

Then, using CSS, set the bullets to `visibility: hidden;` using CSS.

Then, you just need to fool Orbit into thinking that bullets have been clicked when you're actually clicking on something else using jquery's `.click()`. That might look like:

```
$(".yourNavElements").click(function(){ //when you click on your nav element
  $("#theAppropriateBullet").click();   //auto-click on the corresponding bullet
});
```

For this to work, you'll need some way to keep track of which nav button controls which bullet. I stored an index number in a `data` attribute on each nav button, and then targeted bullets that `:contains()` a matching index.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick FYI since I spent more time than I care to admit trying to figure this out myself. Foundation/Orbit now (not sure since when, this is the first I've tried it) now supports deep linking out of the box. Just in case someone else stumbles on this like I did: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/orbit.html